# Change the color of ellipse when mouse over

Tags: wpf

I'm totally new in WPF. It's kind of confusing, why the first code snippet works fine (when mouse over, the color changes) but the second one doesn't work?

```
<Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Opacity="0.5" Stroke="Black" >
<Ellipse.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Ellipse.Style>
```

//

```
<Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" Stroke="Black" >
<Ellipse.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Ellipse.Style>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the line

```
<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
```

Read more on ControlTemplates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Comment: who downvoted this? Please downvote with a comment. The person who asked the question has marked this as an answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but the reasoning is probably that: 1) you indicated where the problem is but didn't explain the problem, and 2) the issue is actually that the `<Ellipse ... Fill="Blue" ...>` overrides anything you set in the style, which is explained well in the [link by Kishore Kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126308/wpf-trigger-wont-set-property-if-set-in-element). The issue is [Dependency Property Setting Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) where #3 Local Value overrides #6 Style Triggers. The example doesn't use Control Templates.

Answer (score 6):

This purely because of the Property value precedence. The below link got an excellent explanation.

[WPF Trigger won't set property if set in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126308/wpf-trigger-wont-set-property-if-set-in-element)

Comment: of course that was the solution but i just gave you the reference when i had the same doubt in my mind.