# Custom ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to create a custom ListBox control in WPF for a chat Messenger. I am using an ellipse to show the online/offline user. The ellipse is to be displayed on left and some text in center of the ListBoxItem.

I want to set the ellipse fill propert to red/green based on some variable.

This is what I have done :

```
<ListBox Name="myList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="117,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Ellipse Name="ellipse" Fill="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="{Binding Online}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Ellipse.Fill" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Ellipse.Triggers>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"></TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>
```

and in the code :

```
myList.Items.Add(new { text="Hello",Online="True"  });
```

I am getting an error as

`Cannot find the static member 'FillProperty' on the type 'ContentPresenter'.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are actually misleading WPF with some of these concerns.

1. Binding A property on trigger will not work. you have to use DataTrigger insteed of Triggers.
2. Implementing Trigger on the Fly for any control. most of the times not work. So go with Styles.
3. While you are creating Ellipse in template make sure you have created enough size for it. So that can be visible to users.

try this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="elstyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Online}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="myList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="117,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Ellipse Name="ellipse" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{DynamicResource elstyle}">
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

code behind .

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                myList.Items.Add(new { Name = "Name" + i.ToString(), Online = Convert.ToBoolean(r.Next(-1, 1)) });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Obviously this is wrong: `Property="{Binding Online}"`

Also you should use a `Style` for triggers, no need to set `TargetName`, and you need to take [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) into consideration, and use a `Setter` for the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the initial colour via a Setter and not in XAML. For more information and see this question: [Change the color of ellipse when mouse over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531516/change-the-color-of-ellipse-when-mouse-over)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few issues in your XAML

- set the size of your `Ellipse`
- you need to use `Style` instead of `Ellipse.Triggers`
- set your `Fill` color in your `Style` if you wane be able to change it in XAML by some condition

here an working example for your problem

```
            <DataTemplate>

                <!--<DockPanel> juste because i like StackPanel-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <!--<Ellipse Name="ellipse" Fill="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Left">-->
                    <Ellipse Name="ellipse" Width="15" Height="15">

                        <!--<Ellipse.Triggers>-->
                        <Ellipse.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">      

                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>

                                <Style.Triggers>

                                    <!--<Trigger Property="{Binding Online}" Value="True">-->
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Online}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LimeGreen"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>

                                </Style.Triggers>

                            </Style>
                        </Ellipse.Style>

                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```