# set ellipse stroke(border color) when mouse enters it in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

Ellipse has a property called IsMouseOver, we can use it to set ellipse color, just like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531516/change-the-color-of-ellipse-when-mouse-over) does.
But in practice, when the mouse is *over* ellipse, the stroke will be changed(image we draw ellipse as a circle), when the mouse is *inside* the ellipse(circle), the color backs to original value.
I know ellipse has an event called *MouseEnter*, we can use EventTrigger, but only StoryBoard can be set in EventTrigger.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="checkButton" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Black"></Ellipse>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtContent" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
        <ContentPresenter />
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard></BeginStoryboard>
        // something like <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" /> here
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

All I want is when MouseEnter happens, set ellipse stroke; when MouseLeave happens, set it back.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my answer and tell why it is wrong ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan actually your answer is correct, and it's the most elegant answer among those answers, it works, it doesn't need Blend SDK, and it's a little bit hacky~ :) P.S. actually the result is a little bit different from what I expected, but I modified the code to make it right, I already post a comment under your answer, please check. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete solution for a custom CheckBox :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfControlTemplates.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomChkBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="checkButton" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Property=BorderBrush}"></Ellipse>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtContent" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Property=Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="checkButton" Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="checkButton" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Template="{StaticResource CustomChkBox}" Width="100" Height="25" Foreground="Red" Content="Newsletters " Background="#FF16CF38" BorderBrush="#FF14C9C9"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To change Ellipse Stroke properties using Storyboard :

Trick is to set Stroke property differntly so that we can access it from StoryBoard. StoryBoard doesn't have any animation for Brush, but it does have one for Color.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="checkButton" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="5" Margin="82,0,61,0">

    <Ellipse.Stroke>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="StrokeColor" Color="Red"/>
    </Ellipse.Stroke>

    <Ellipse.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
         <BeginStoryboard  x:Name="EllipseSB">
           <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness" To="10"/>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StrokeColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Blue"/>
           </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
         </EventTrigger>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
             <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EllipseSB"/>
         </EventTrigger>

    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: who has downvoted this answer. dont downvote without giving proper comment.

Comment: Your method is correct and it uses a trick, thanks in advance! But the result is that, when mouse enters the ellipse, the Stroke changes; but if mouse is **INSIDE** the ellipse, the Stroke changes back. I need the stroke stays the same when the mouse is inside it. The solution is simple, add property `Fill="White"` to ellipse, make it like a _complete_ circle, not a disk whose border's stroke changes. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user1108069 Fill="Transparent" is more suitable for StoryBoard animation scenario.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot, and I got a question..where do you get these knowledge? Just MSDN? or some books or websites ?

Comment: @user1108069 MSDN is very poor for WPF. It was great earlier, but now it has lost its sheen. But still for documentation you have to look for MSDN. I scratched my head with WPF since 2012, and gave up in frustration every time. WPF is a technology ahead of its time, but poorly documented. So, my advice from my exp is focus on concepts, and how they relate to each other. Dont go deep inside. For example, why and where we use Trigger/Command/Dep-Property/INotifyPropertyChanged/Binding/Templates and so on. And regarding debugging, look for stacktrace in debugger, see exception carefully ...

Comment: ... try apply own logic. Take random question from this site and build your WPF project demonstrating this problem, then compare your answer with others. A 10 day exercise will bring big changes in your knowledge. Use ILSpy tool extensively and peek inside code. This will boost your confidence exponentially. Learning Expression BLEND is a must to fully explore WPF, it is fun. Very good books "learn expression blend step by step ebook", "expression blend unleashed ", "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-511): Windows Application Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4" .

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" TargetName="checkButton"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: actually it doesn't help, this method is exactly the same with the link I mentioned in question description, what I need is when mouse is **INSIDE** the ellipse, the color changes, not **HOVER**. So, sorry, downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> All I want is when MouseEnter happens, set ellipse stroke; when MouseLeave happens, set it back.

There are few ways to do this

using simple style triggers and setters

```
  <Ellipse Fill="White" StrokeThickness="10">
    <Ellipse.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
         <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
           <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Green"/>
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Ellipse.Style>
</Ellipse>
```

using blend behavior (using blend SDK)

```
 <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="109,116,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Stroke">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Stroke">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Don't forget to add references to `Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions` and `System.Windows.Interaactivity`

It is pretty verbose if you do this in visual studio.But if you use Expresssion Blend trust me it's just only few clicks.

Comment: This needs Blend SDK.

Comment: What if user is setting Stroke, you don't its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="checkButton" Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Black" Fill="AliceBlue">
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                    To="Red" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="Black"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtContent" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
    <ContentPresenter />
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```