# Make correct display selected elements for any OS (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ListView

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="800" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}"  Foreground="Black" >
                                </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="800" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

First TextBlock - Foreground="Black"
Second TextBlock - foreground not specified.

In selected item in ListView first TextBlock `foreground="Black"` (appears incorrectly in every OS), second TextBlock - foreground default(appears correctly in every OS).

What i need:

In selected item in ListView first TextBlock foreground must be default too and appears correctly in every OS, but I can't change TextBlock foreground directly(in trigger or style).

Have any idea? May be I can reset Foreground of First TextBlock (no set default foreground! exactly RESET). Or  reset style to default ??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand - what is OS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question right, but here`s my guess: you can`t change `Foreground` of your first `TextBlock` because it is set explicitly. Just remove foreground definition from control itself and set it in style, that should make it overridable by other styles and triggers.

There are answers with more details (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7126401/1021555)), so your question is somewhat duplicate. Well, that is if I got it right =)