# Button Color WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm trying to change my button color when the mouse is over it but it's not working (the button is still blue) and all examples I find go like I'm doing:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#424242"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8BC34A"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could try and use `<Setter Property="Background.Color" .../>`

Comment: It doesn't recognize as a property if I use `Background.Color`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - button mouse over change color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073294/wpf-button-mouse-over-change-color)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ControlTemplate` for this purpose like this:

```
<Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#424242"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                       <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                      </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8BC34A"/>
             </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Button.Style>
```