# Custom Style Button With Modified Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have a `Button` that I want to have an Orange `Background` with a White `Foreground`. When I mouse over the `Button` I would like it to display in `DarkOrange`. This is the `Style` I am using at the moment.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>                      
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If I don't modify the original `Background` color of the my `Button` this style works fine. For example;

`<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="SIGN IN" />`

has no issues. However, when I want to change the default `Background` of the `Button`, i.e

`<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="SIGN IN" Background="Orange"/>`

the style does not work. I assume this is because I am now overriding the `Background` property that the `IsMouseOver` is attempting to change.

Is there a way I can achieve both a modified default `Background` and a `IsMouseOver` effect? I have also tried setting `<Border Background="Orange">` but to no effect still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `setter` to your `Style` instead of adding a `Background` property to your `Button`. Like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
       ...
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
       ... 
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151803/2946329) is an another example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="Border" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="CP" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="CP" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This working fine with

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="SIGN IN" Background="Orange"/>
```