# Change color of WPF button using code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF triangle button which is made using Polygon-geometry:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Formats.Triangle_Down"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Formats"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="100" Width="100">
<Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Button" Foreground="Transparent" Margin="0,0,50,0">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Polygon x:Name="triangle" Points="10,10 20,30 30,10"  Stroke="Lime"
                     StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Lime" Margin="0,0,-91,-85">
                        </Polygon>
                    </Grid>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

So my question is: how can I change `Background` color and `Borderbrush` of my `Button` using C# code?
When I use this:

```
button.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

nothing changes (if I have not mistaken, because it doesn't change filling of polygon).
I know the way to change color using "border"

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
<Button.Content>
</Border>
```

But it doesn't suit me 'cause form of my button is triangle.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151663/button-color-wpf/33151803#33151803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you put your polygon inside grid and bind that grid background to `Button.Background`, while hardcoding color of your polygon to `Lime`. That way you cannot change color of polygon later. Instead - bind polygon colors to `Button.Background`:

```
<Button Background="Lime"
        Content="Button"
        Foreground="Transparent"
        Margin="0,0,50,0">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Polygon x:Name="triangle"
                     Points="10,10 20,30 30,10"
                     Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     StrokeThickness="2"
                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                     Margin="0,0,-91,-85"></Polygon>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Then changing `Button.Background` will change colors of polygon.