# Setting background color of button at runtime not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that have the following code in the mouse enter event:

```
private void CloseB_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  CloseB.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

But when the mouse enters, the color of the button turns to a weird light-blue (almost white) color.
I already tried to set opacity to 1 and to set Background property as :
`new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`
It is located in a grid with Background color set to Black. And the original color of the button is also black.
I don't know what I am missing.
Note: variable **CloseB** is my button.

Comment: What you are seeing is the color when the button is mouse-over. The Background color you set is the color in normal state (without mouse-over). Is it Red after the mouse is moved out?

Comment: No, but only because I have another method that sets Background color to black again after the mouse leaves.

Comment: Thank you. I would never thought of that. But now I have another problem to fix.

Comment: Welcome. The button has many defined states, like disabled state, focused state, pressed state, each state has a different background color. To achieve your requirement, you need to learn how to edit the button's `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to use trigger. So first apply style in button definition and define trigger for your event.

Answer (score 0):

As @kennyzx mentioned, the color I saw was the default color of the button when mouse is over.
I fixed my problem removing my Backgroung property in the button xaml and adding a style based on : [Change color of Button when Mouse is over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073294/change-color-of-button-when-mouse-is-over)