# How to disable a button and change it's color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have this code I found on here, that generates me a grid of buttons - I know this may not be the best way to do this, but for now I'd like to do it this way, I am quite new at this. So the button should be either `Black`(`1`) or `White`(`0`), depending on it's value. This all works, until I hover the button and I can see it's value. If I just add the `Visibility` property = "false" to the button, it does not even get displayed.

[image: A grid of black and white buttons where one is hovered that shows a black one digit as content and light blue background with a blue border.]

This is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="1,1,1,1">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then I display the grid here:

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,10,-636" Grid.Row="3">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="automata" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" Margin="0,0,0,-119"/>
</Grid>
```

I would also be happy of a recommendation on how to display these values in another way.

Comment: Give the button an x:Name="YourButtonName" attribute. That will allow you to change properties in code behind.

Comment: You can also bind your color to a property in the View Model, and manipulate it from there.  Probably a better approach than code-behind.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073294/change-color-of-button-when-mouse-is-over

Comment: If you don't intend to show the number in any case, remove `Content="{Binding}"`.

Comment: The correct solution is to override the template of the Button like Ash suggested.  This way you can change the mouse over behavior. Don't use data binding or code-behind for this task. You can even move the existing triggers for the background and foreground to the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance or visual states of a control, create a style with a  `ControlTemplate` that fits your requirements. You can also [extract the default style using Blen or Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599) and adapt it.

In the following, I took the default style with its control template for `Button` and commented out the triggers for *MouseOver*, *Pressed* and other states so they are ineffective, but you still see where to continue since your question certainly is only the starting point for further customization. I adapted and added your triggers to the `ControlTemplate`. What this does is simply show a black button for `1` and white for `0`.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
   </Style.Resources>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                     <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

               <!-- These are the default triggers, which you might customize to fit your style. -->
               <!--<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
               </Trigger>-->

               <!-- These are your triggers, which now act on the Content property of the templated button. -->
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="1">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="0">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
               </DataTrigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use this style in your data template and you should get the expected result.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
   <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="1,1,1,1" Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Since you try to make the text `1` and `0` *invisible* by setting the background and foreground to the same color, you could also simply remove the `ContentPresenter` from the `ControlTemplate`, so there is no content displayed at all and the `Foreground` setters are not needed.

Another thing to note is that your binary state maybe suggests to use a [`ToggleButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead.

> Base class for controls that can switch states, such as `CheckBox`.

This is an example style for a `ToggleButton` that does not show content and sets the background like in your question, but dependening on its `IsChecked` property.

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
   </Style.Resources>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                     <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Change the binding in your data template from `Content` to `IsChecked`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
   <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="1,1,1,1" Style="{DynamicResource MyToggleButtonStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This buys you the advantage of toggling the states automatically, but only if you can provide a property for two-way binding (getter and setter), otherwise an exception will be thrown.