# How can I set the "pressed" color on a custom button?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a very simple inherited `UiButton`, with some custom styling:

```
internal class UiButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public UiButton()
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x6E, 0x6E, 0x6E));
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x4A, 0x4A, 0x4A));
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
    }
}
```

Which I add to a XAML `Grid`. This all works fine, except the background color changes after I clicked it once. I try to play with triggers, but I don't seem to get it right.

```
        Style = new Style();

        Trigger isPressed = new Trigger();
        isPressed.Property = IsPressedProperty;
        isPressed.Value = true;

        Setter backgroundSetter = new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
        isPressed.Setters.Add(backgroundSetter);

        Style.Triggers.Add(isPressed);
```

This code crashes with

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'After a 'TriggerCollection' is in use (sealed), it cannot be modified.'

How can I make sure my "pressed" background is the same as the default?

Comment: Is there a reason to not add that style in the xaml?

Comment: @egeer No. I tried that as well, but failed to read that style in my `UiButton`

Comment: Got it. Are you just trying to setup a standard style for that button across the window? Do you need that inherited Button for anything else or is it just the styling? Or I guess a better way of asking it - what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @egeer the ultimate goal is to have a button I can replicate many times in a Grid (so they cannot be static in the XAML), but they were designed by a UX designer and he decided on certain colors.

Comment: Controls have default colors defined for behaviour via static resources defined in Generic.xaml. The "simplest" thing is to override one of these statics with your own color resource. e.g. StaticResource ControlPressedColor.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle the hover and pressed colors is to override the template. While you can do this in the codebehind, it will probably be more work. That said, you can still inherit the button and include xaml to achieve what you are looking for.

codebehind:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UiButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UiButton : Button
    {
        public UiButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

xaml

```xml
<Button x:Class="StackOverflowAnswers.Wpf.UiButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowAnswers.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="450"
        d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="5"
                                BorderBrush="#6E6E6E"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="#4A4A4A" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                 Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                                    Value="DarkGoldenrod" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                                    Value="Red" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

[image]

You can check out these other posts for more info on overriding that template:

- [How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)
- [Change color of Button when Mouse is over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073294/change-color-of-button-when-mouse-is-over)