# style trigger on .Net 4.5 RibbonToggleButton SmallImageSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, .net-4.5, ribbon

I have the following Style for my RibbonToggleButton

```
                <Style TargetType="RibbonToggleButton">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Source="Images/small_checked.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Source="Images/small_unchecked.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

I also tried the full path for the SmallImageSource property:

```
 "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource.SmallImageSource"
```

But i always get this error:

> Error  1   Cannot resolve the Style Property 'SmallImageSource'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property. Line ....

**Update "Solution"**

```
<RibbonToggleButton.Style>
    <Style>
        <!-- set the affected properties only here -->
        <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="Images/small_unchecked.png"/>
        <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="Images/large_unchecked.png"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="Images/small_checked.png"/>
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="Images/large_checked.png"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</RibbonToggleButton.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a target type to your style?

So it would be `<Style TargetType="RibbonToggleButton">`instead of just
`<Style>`

Comment: This helps to find the property, because i tried to style it firstly this way: <RibbonToggleButton.Sytle> but that doesn't work.

Now i get this "Error 3 The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "ImageSource"."

Comment: According to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontogglebutton.smallimagesource.ASPX) it is just expecting the string so maybe try this: <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="Images/small_checked.png">

Comment: sometimes it could be so easy, tanks NAJ

Comment: Inside the RibbonControl i don't get it to work, i tried a simple ToggleButton as well...

Comment: now i have it ;) compared with this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126308/wpf-trigger-wont-set-property-if-set-in-element
i have to set the default values of the affected properties only inside the style. see updated question