# WPF DataBinding Not Updating Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF project that I'm working on with a custom title bar. In making the minimize/maximize button, I came across something that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. When I set the `Visibility` property explicitly on the control, the trigger no longer is able to update that property.  I've verified that the trigger fires properly using WPF Inspector and it works perfectly when I don't set the `Visibility` property explicitly and instead let it get it's value from the trigger.

I know that I can just not set the property explicitly and have a working solution; however, this seems to go against what I know about how triggers are supposed to function. So really, I'm looking for an explanation as to why it doesn't work and, if possible, how to get it to work when setting the property explicitly.

Here is the complete WPF example app I made the closely mimics what I'm trying to do. What should happen is the `Collapsed` button should take the place of the `Visible` button when the `WindowState` goes from `Maximized` to `Normal` and visa versa. The button on the last column is the one that works where the property is not set explicitly.

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonVisibilityTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonVisibilityTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="btn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="#E6E6E6">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="#C6C6C6">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#000000">
            <Grid Width="8" Height="8">
                <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="9" Height="9"/>
            </Grid>

            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource btn}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <!-- Doesn't Work -->
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#000000" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid Width="8" Height="8">
                <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="9" Height="1"/>
            </Grid>

            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource btn}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <!-- Works -->
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#000000">
            <Grid Width="8" Height="8">
                <Rectangle Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="9" Height="1"/>
            </Grid>

            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource btn}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, you can read up on this phenomenon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7126401/6741868). I hope it clears your doubts, what it says is basically that "setting property value" is at #3 precedence, while "using styles & triggers" is at #6.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, thank you for finding that, apparently my GoogleFu has failed me. That's exactly the answer and definition I was looking for.