# Border trigger based on viewmodel type doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datatrigger

I have a MainView - which has a property "ViewModel" - When I change this ViewModel to a different type, I set update the datacontext on the window to the specific viewmodel and then I use a ContentControl and a DataTemplate to change some content - This all works.

Now I try to create a trigger to change the background of a border based on the viewmodel type - And I came up with this:

```
<Border Background="#3f3f3f" CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Type viewmodels:AllBeadsViewModel}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
        <Image Height="32" Source="/Images/Icons/bookmark-1.png" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
        <TextBlock Text="All Beads" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I used a WPF Inspector to try and make sure that the datacontext is correct (AllBeadsViewModel) and that the setter is described correctly - All seems to match. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] showing clearly what you're trying to do, what doesn't work, and what precisely you want instead, it's impossible to know for sure what a good answer would be. However, in the code you posted, you appear to be comparing the object itself with an instance of `System.Type`. Unless your object is a `Type`, that will never succeed. Maybe instead you'd like to write a converter for the binding, which calls `GetType()` on the object (i.e. converts an object to its type). Then the comparison would make sense.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for your reply. It's really hard to know how much info to put into the question. I can link my entire sourcecode sure - But that would just create too much noise.
So my Window.DataContext is a class, a AllBeadsViewModel or EditBeadViewModel - Based on which one it is, I would like a border switch background color. So yes I was checking the type. And I see your point. So I did a converter. First I tried matching value.GetType() to {x:Type viewmodels:AllBeadsViewModel} - That didn't work - So I tried matching value.GetType().Name to "AllBeadsViewModel" - Still no effect

Comment: Keep in mind also that an explicit value set in an element will override any attempt to set it in a style. In addition to the converter, you should remove the `Background="#3f3f3f"` from the `Border` element declaration, and add `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f3f"/>` to the style.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That did it! I did not realize that you couldn't have an initial property like that but that you had to add a setter. If you make an "answer" I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the XAML you posted.

The first is the immediate question, how to set a trigger based on an object's type. Your `<DataTrigger/>` element is referencing the current data context in the `Binding` property, and then referencing the *type* of the object in the `Value` property. So, this is asking WPF to compare *the data context object itself* with an instance of `System.Type`. Since your data context object isn't in fact a type, this will never trigger.

To resolve that, you need a mechanism to compare the *type* of your current data context object with the `AllBeadsViewModel` type. There are, as is typically the case with WPF, several different options. But IMHO one of the simplest is to write an `IValueConverter` for the trigger's binding that simply returns the result of `GetType()` on the bound value.

Now, that done the XAML you posted still won't update the border's background color based on the trigger, because the explicit setting of the `Background` property in the `<Border/>` element [takes precedence over any setter found in a style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). To fix that, you'll need to remove the explicit property value assignment, and replace it with a `<Setter/>` element in the style itself:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Style>
        <p:Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f3f"/>
            <!-- etc. -->
        </p:Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <!-- etc. -->
</Border>
```

(You can ignore the `p:` XML namespace I've added to the `<Style/>` elements above…that's just there because the Stack Overflow code formatter for XML/XAML gets confused by the unqualified `<Style/>` elements and stops formatting as XML until the elements are closed.)

See also [WPF Trigger won't set property if set in Element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7126308) for discussion on this second aspect/problem of your XAML.