# Access to main window control in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have `Window` and three `UserControl` in my Project, I have a control that show usercontrol in itself

```
<Window x:Class="Hesabdar.winMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:pageTransitions="clr-namespace:WpfPageTransitions;assembly=WpfPageTransitions"
        Title="winMain" Height="500" Width="600" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Grid>
        <pageTransitions:PageTransition Name="pageTransitionControl"  TransitionType="SlideAndFade" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in `UserControl` I have `Button`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Hesabdar.ucMain"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="500" Width="600">
    <Grid>
          <Button Content="Manege" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,163,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How is it possible control `pageTransitionControl` from `UserControl` to navigate `pageTransitionControl` to other `userControl`

**Edit:**

Code Behind of MainWindow :

```
ucMain objUC = new ucMain(); //Declare Instance Of user Control 
pageTransitionControl.ShowPage(objUC); // Show Instance of usercontrol in PageTransitionControl
```

Just I want to run method `ShowPage` of `pageTransitionControl` in mainWindow from click of button that is in `UserControl`.

Comment: Take a look in the answer I gave to my question in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059120/change-wpf-usercontrol-depending-on-a-property-of-a-treeviewitem

Comment: it seems that my goal is different from you, More Info Added @Romano Zumbé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the PageTransition control like this from the UserControls code behind:

```
public static PageTransition FindPageControl(DependencyObject child)
{
    DependencyObject parent= VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    PageTransition page = parent as PageTransition;
    if (page != null)
    {
        return page;
    }
    else
    {
        return FindPageControl(parent);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
this.FindPageControl(this).ShowPage(...);
```

Comment: it Works! you cast parent as `PageTransition` , but as i know parent of this control is window.as i know it is recursive code but how cast has been done and no error occure  !?

Comment: It works because of the `as` operator, which does not cause an exception if the cast is impossible. Instead it returns a value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is to use MVVM pattern. Use a ContentControl instead. And pass the usercontrol reference to its Content property. you can get idea from it, like :

```
yourContentControl.Content = new UserControl1();
```

Comment: Code Edited and more info added